# SQL placeholders in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, placeholder

I searched SO and Google but was unable to make sense of the explanations nor was I able to tell if they were related.

This is my WHERE clause for this report:

```
WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124) )
```

When the user goes to run the report, the WHERE clause auto populates the information they enter for Production Date, and the Customer Key.

For this report I had to create several variables that are called in the set section. Here is an example:

```
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
);
```

For this WHERE clause in the SET area I need the WHERE clause to populate with the production date and customer key that the user inputs when running the report. Is there a way to do this?
Let me know if I need to provide more explanation.

I am only using SQL. Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What products are you using?  sql-server?  MySQL?   Any front end application languages?    What tool/language is used to create the "report"?

Comment: @TabAlleman I am only using SQL. Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define variables for the specific values you want replaced.  Assuming this is SQL Server you are talking about, this would work, but you would have to know that if for @key, the below will not work for comma separated values, only singleton values.  If you need comma separated values, then you may need dynamic sql.  I took at stab at the datatypes, fix as needed.

```
declare @ts1 datetime,
    @ts2 datetime,
    @key int;

set @ts1 = '2015-06-24 00:00:00';
set @ts2 = '2015-06-24 00:00:00';
set @key = 124;

SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= @ts1 
    AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= @ts2
        OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (@key)) 
);
```

Comment: when I try to do this I get the error 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '<'.
This is the error I get after only adding the three variables, not editing the WHERE clause.

Comment: you are supposed to remove the greater/less than signs.  i will update my example above with your hard-coded values.

Comment: that makes sense however, the value will not always be 6/24, it will be whatever the user inputs right before they run the report.

Comment: Right, so you will need to figure out how to set those values from whatever reporting tool you are using. I put those in there as placeholders, to show you how you can use variables.  If you cannot figure out how to set the variable values, that is a whole different thread question then.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for helping me get started. I will create a new question.